# Infinite redirect after htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /worksheet/

# \?\S matches at least one character after ?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(worksheet/rebus)/\?\S [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rebus/?$ /worksheet/rebus/? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1&showSol=$3 [L,QSA]
```

I changed it for

```
xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/?random=testing11
```

to be forwarded for

```
xyz.com/worksheet/rebus/
```

buts its endup in infinite redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Please make sure you keep your htaccess Rules file along with worksheet folder NOT inside worksheet folder.

Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /worksheet/

# \?\S matches at least one character after ?
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(worksheet/rebus)/\?\S [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^rebus/?$ /worksheet/rebus/? [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1&showSol=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?url=$2&tableName=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?tableName=$1 [L,QSA]
```